# firebase error Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a program on Android that uses the Firebase database, but I have problems right now.

It's my code MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

So far, the results I found were in line with the line of code that I should add, and I've done this and I have not yet heard about the removal of the error.

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're missing the google-services plugin in your dependencies. The firebase android documentation mentions that these plugins should be added:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem I have now :  Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Are you dependencies inside the buildscript brackets? 
It might also help if you show your entire build.gradle file.